# How to load Opencv's fisherfaces algorithm on Android Studio?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, android-studio, android

I create on yml file on my desktop that can be read by Opencv's fisherfaces model. But on Android Studio there is not a class called Fisherface. What I have to do to create a Fisherface model and load my yml file?

Thanks.

Comment: the current 2.4 java wrappers are broken here, please wait for [opencv3.0](http://opencv3-javadocs.appspot.com/doc/org/opencv/face/package-summary.html)

Comment: Thanks for your help berak, do you know another solution for my problem? I really need a solution for this. I have to load this yml file on android. This is my term paper and I have to finish it in 1 month to graduate.

Comment: aww, did not see, it was *you*. (you asked the same thing a year ago already, right ? well, not much has changed in the meantime

Comment: Ohh yes, it was you that helped me!!! =D I did it what you said to me and I got it working. So if I download an older version of opencv and use eclipse with ndk I can do what you said to me?

Comment: you probably don't need to downgrade your opencv version, but for 2.4 you will still need to create a wrapper for cv::createFisherFaceRecognizer() via JNI

Comment: Can I create a wrapper on android studio? Man, you are really helping me again, I will put your name o my term paper!! hahaha

Comment: sorry, but i don't know android studion *at all*.

Comment: I will try to create an wrapper using android studio. I let you know if I can, otherwise I'll go to eclipse. Thanks man!!!